# psql shortcut for frequently used queries? (like Unix "alias")

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Is it possible to somehow create aliases (like Unix `alias` command) in psql?

I mean, not SQL FUNCTION, but local aliases to ease manual queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a view? May be [views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html) will help in your case.

Answer (score 24):

I don't know about any possibility. There is only workaround for *psql* based on *psql* variables, but there is lot of limits - using parameters for this queries is difficult.

```
postgres=# \set whoami 'SELECT CURRENT_USER;'
postgres=# :whoami
 current_user 
--------------
pavel
(1 row)
```

Comment: Basically it seems like views are just better, no? I guess what I'm looking for (local aliases) is just not "in the spirit" of db admin. I should just add some usual views whenever I'm setting up a database.

Comment: Depends on what you want. But main usage of views is a simplicity queries (generally simplification of working with data) and security reason, so probably you would to use a views :)

Comment: How can this be persisted so that other sessions can also use the same variable?

Comment: @NarayanBhat - you can set it in `.psqlrc`

Answer (score 12):

Pavel's answer is almost correct, except you can use parameter in another way.

after

```
\set s 'select * from '
\set l ' limit 10;'
```

The following command

```
:s agent :l
```

will equal to

```
select * from agent limit 10;
```

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html

> If an unquoted argument begins with a colon (:), it is taken as a psql
>   variable and the value of the variable is used as the argument
>   instead. If the variable name is surrounded by single quotes (e.g.
>   :'var'), it will be escaped as an SQL literal and the result will be
>   used as the argument. If the variable name is surrounded by double
>   quotes, it will be escaped as an SQL identifier and the result will be
>   used as the argument.

You can also use backquote to run shell command

> Arguments that are enclosed in backquotes (`) are taken as a command
>   line that is passed to the shell. The output of the command (with any
>   trailing newline removed) is taken as the argument value. The above
>   escape sequences also apply in backquotes.

Answer (score 1):

how about using UDFs? You can create a UDF that returns a table (set of) then you can query it as this: select * from udf();

It is not as clean, but it is better than nothing and it is portable. And UDFs can take parameters too.

Comment: I wanted something that is not storing anything in the db, but again this is not the "spirit" of how things are working, so there is no good answer. Views are more adapted in my case, so I will accept an answer talking about views.

Answer (score -1):

This might help, if you need to run frequent queries from command line (not from psql cli).

Add this to `.bash_profile` /`.bashrc`

```
POSTGRES_BIN=~/Postgres/bin
B_RED='\033[1;31m'
RESET='\033[0m'

psqlcommand="$POSTGRES_BIN/psql -U vignesh usersdb -q -c"

function psqlselectrows()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "SELECT * from $1"
}
```

The above command selects rows from the table, passed in the argument.

**Note:**

1. Change the database name, as required.
2. The schema by default is public. To have another default schema, add the following line in `~/.psqlrc` file.

`SET SEARCH_PATH TO <schema_name>;`

3. If the database is password protected, [refer this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt) and make use of the secure method.

I have made some commands for my use, if it might help.

1. **psqlselectrows** - To select rows from a table
2. **psqlgettablecount** - To get row count of a table
3. **psqltruncatetable** - To truncate a table, on prompt
4. **psqlgettablesize** - To get the size of a table
5. **psqlgetvacuumdetails** - To get vacuum details of a table
6. **psqlsettings** - To get default and modified settings configured for Postgres.

(All the above commands need table name as first argument)

```
#Colors
B_RED='\033[1;31m'
B_GREEN='\033[1;32m'
B_YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
RESET='\033[0m'

#Postgres Command With Params
psqlcommand="$POSTGRES_BIN/psql -U vignesh usersdb -q -c"

function psqlgettablesize()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('$1')) as total_table_size, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('$1')) as table_size, pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size('$1')) as index_size;";
}
function psqlgettablecount()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "select count(*) from $1;"
}
function psqlgetvacuumdetails()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "SELECT relname, n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, last_analyze::timestamp, analyze_count, last_autoanalyze::timestamp, autoanalyze_count, last_vacuum::timestamp, vacuum_count, last_autovacuum::timestamp, autovacuum_count FROM pg_stat_user_tables where relname='$1' and schemaname = current_schema();"
}
function psqltruncatetable()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    {
        read -p "$(echo -e ${B_YELLOW}"Are you sure to truncate table '$1' (y/n)? "${RESET})" choice
        case "$choice" in
            y|Y ) $psqlcommand "TRUNCATE $1;";;
            n|N ) echo -e "${B_GREEN}Table '$1' not truncated${RESET}";;
            * ) echo -e "${B_RED}Invalid option${RESET}";;
        esac
    }
}
function psqlsettings()
{
    query="select * from pg_settings"
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        query="$query where category like '%$1%'"
    fi
    query="$query ;"
    $psqlcommand "$query"
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo -e "${B_YELLOW}Passing Category as first argument will filter the related settings.${RESET}"
    fi
}
function psqlselectrows()
{
    [ -z "$1" ] && echo -e "${B_RED}Argument 1 missing: Need table name${RESET}" ||
    $psqlcommand "SELECT * from $1"
}
```